# Taxinomy slug as var in parent archive page, without having a specific taxinomy page

Tags: javascript, taxonomy, archives, slug

I'm not exactly sure of the best way to ask what I am trying to achieve, so I'm going to describe it here. If someone can identify a more succinct way to ask this, or if it's been answered in a different way, please let me know!

For example sake, I going to describe a photographer's WordPress site, where there would be a Portfolio archive page listing available taxonomies, say Nature, Landscape, and Portraits.

This Portfolio page had a grid of entries, displayed from all various Portfolio taxonomies. Above the grid, would be a navigation bar listing those taxonomies:

**All | Nature | Landscape | Portraits**

When one of the taxonomy menu options is clicked, the grid filters to the user selection using JavaScript. For example, when "Nature" is clicked, only Nature entries are shown and all others are invisible.

The Nature taxonomy would also have its own page, accessed via the slug: mysite.com/portfolio/nature - I do not want this page to exist.

I would like to be able to use that Nature URL above to go to the Portfolio archive page and have it filtered to the Nature entries by JavaScript when the page is ready.

**Essentially, I would like the URL mysite.com/portfolio/nature to act as mysite.com/portfolio/?tax=nature** - where the tax GET var would get registered in PHP (and later outputted to JavaScript) and then the parent Portfolio archive page is loaded.

I'm not looking for any help with the actual JavaScript implementation of this, I'm looking for advice for how to handle the URL rewriting(?) in WordPress.

What's the best way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Is this the built-in `post` post type, or a custom type? What is the URL structure for individual portfolio posts? It would also help to see the code you use to register the taxonomy, as those arguments let you disable taxonomy archives if you're not using them.

Comment: The theme being used is Inspiro by WPZOOM. The post type is the default "Portfolio" type which ships with the theme - so a custom post type. The URL structure for individual items is mysite.com/portfolio/project/individual-item-slug. So /project/ would need to still function while the other taxonomy slugs are filtered. Can you let me know more detail about what code you need to see? I have not made any custom additions for registering the taxonomy. Thanks Milo.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea (I'm not sure it's the most efficient) is to do a redirection in the file `category.php` or `archive.php` depending of your theme.

Try with this code before the `get_header()` line :

```
$term = get_queried_object();


if (    ("category" === $term->taxonomy)
    &&  (0 !== $term->parent) // if it's not a 1st level category
) {

    // get the parent
    $parent = get_term($term->parent);


    // redirection

    $url = get_term_link($parent) . "#" . $term->slug;

    wp_redirect($url);
    exit();

}
```

this code only work with a 2 levels taxonomy because the redirection ends at the 1st level.

Comment: Thanks mmm, I can give this a try. I think I would prefer a solution that does not rely on redirection, but this is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

First, register a custom query var to pass the taxonomy term. We want this value to be ignored by the query, so we won't use the taxonomy's actual slug in the rule.

```
function wpd_add_query_var( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'wpd_term';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_add_query_var' );
```

For the rule, we just need to set `post_type=slug` to trigger a post type archive, where `slug` is the slug that the post type was registered with. If you're not sure what this is, you can see it in the URL when viewing that post type's list screen in admin. We also set our custom query var to whatever was passed in the URL.

```
function wp_add_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'portfolio/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=portfolio&wpd_term=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wp_add_rewrite_rule' );
```

Visit the Settings > Permalinks admin page to flush rules after adding this.

You can then access the value after the query is parsed with `get_query_var( 'wpd_term' )`.

Also have a look at [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and [`wp_localize_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) functions for getting that value into your script.

Comment: Thanks Milo. With these two scripts in functions.php, what should I see when I now visit "portfolio/nature/"? I was expecting to see the portfolio index page, with "nature" stored in wpd_term, but I'm still seeing the nature taxonomy page. I've uploaded functions.php and flushed the Permalinks.

Comment: Also, get_query_var( 'wpd_term' ) is empty when called later on that taxonomy page. Did I miss something?

Comment: It's probably an issue of priority. You can add a third argument to `add_action` so the rule is added later and overrides the rules generated by the taxonomy registration. You can also use [`register_taxonomy_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_taxonomy_args/) filter to set `rewrite` to false for that taxonomy.